Double integral over arbitrarily small disk.
Suppose that $f$ is continuous on a disk that contains the point $(a, b)$. Let $D_r$ be the closed disk with center $(a, b)$ and radius $r$. Use the Mean Value Theorem for double integrals to show that
$$
\lim _{r \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\pi r^2} \iint_D f(x, y) d A=f(a, b)
$$
This post exists because the author counldn't find a freely-accessible proof of this property on the internet. This problem is taken from Stewart's Calculus 9th Edition Exercise 15.2.

By Mean Value Theorem:
$\exists x_0, y_0$ such that $\iint_D f(x,y) d A = f(x_0, y_0)\pi r^2$ where $(x_0,y_0) \in D$ and $D$ is the disk centered at $(a,b)$ with radius $r$.
Multiply both sides by $\frac{1}{\pi r^2}$ to get
$$
\frac{1}{\pi r^2} \iint f(x,y) d A = f(x_0,y_0)
$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$
\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\pi r^2}\iint f(x,y) d A = \lim_{r\rightarrow 0}f(x_0,y_0)
$$
$f$ is continuous at $(a,b)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} f(x_0,y_0)=f(a,b)$
So we have
$$
\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\pi r^2}\iint f(x,y) d A = f(a,b)
$$
